# Is it possible to get values from RxJS without a .subscribe method?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm looking for a way to use RxJS's pipeline operators to improve my existing code.

Instead of this:

```js
export const initialState = {}

export const createReducerActions = (
    actionType => ({
        [actionType]: (
            (prevState, { data }) => (
                data
            )
        ),
    })
)

const createDataStorageReducer = (
    actionType => (
        createReducer(
            (
                createReducerActions(
                    actionType,
                )
            ),
            (
                initialState
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

I'm looking to see if some sort of `executeImmediately` function exists in RxJS like so:

```js
export const initialState = {}

export const createReducerActions = (
    actionType => ({
        [actionType]: (
            (prevState, { data }) => (
                data
            )
        ),
    })
)

const createDataStorageReducer = (
    actionType => (
        of(actionType)
        .pipe(
            map(createReducerActions),
            map(reducerActions => (
                createReducer(
                    reducerActions,
                    initialState,
                )
            ))
        )
        .executeImmediately()
    )
)
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve with your `executeImmediately`? Or what problem you have that can't be solved with `subscribe()`, `toPromise()` or `forEach()`?

Comment: Those are async methods. I'd have to provide a callback. In this case, I want to just grab the value that occurs immediately after the function completes. In the first example, it returns the result of `createReducer()`. In the second example, with `executeImmediately`, it's the same functionality. With subscribe, I'd have to pass in a callback method to get the value of `createReducer()`.

Comment: This isn't true. Basically everything in RxJS that doesn't work with time is synchronous. Only when you use eg. `delay()`, `bufferTime`, ... or similar operators you'll get asynchronous behavior.

Comment: How do I get the value from an Observable without a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the value of an `Observable` synchronously.  The closest that you can get is to create a `BehaviorSubject`, subscribe that to an `Observable`.  You can then get the value of a `BehaviorSubject` synchronously.

```js
console.log(typeof(rxjs.BehaviorSubject));

const o = rxjs.interval(1000);
const bs = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject("hello");

bs.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
o.subscribe(bs);

bs.next("world");

// You can get the current value of a BS with getValue()
console.log(`bs value right now is: ${bs.getValue()}`);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`bs value after 3 seconds is: ${bs.getValue()}`);
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So it looks like all these RxJS operators are essentially async only. If I want to synchronously pull values off of them, there's no way to guarantee the value is what I want it to be.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes I mean, that's kind of their intention.  Their intention is to notify listeners that things have happened.  They are "push" objects, not pull.  Consider the table that RxJS puts forward: [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable).  Pulling from them defeats their purpose.

Comment: I'd like to be able to reuse those operators anywhere though. I guess, in my particular example, I could do it with an array reduce, something like a `pipe` or `compose` method since I'll I'm doing is `map`.